# Are multiple-inherited constructors called multiple times?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Are multiple-inherited constructors called multiple times? And in what order are constructors called? Does this depend on the order in the inheritance list?

Here is an example (it's only for making the situation clear, no real-life example).

```
class Base {};
class DerivedBaseOne : public Base {};
class DerivedBaseTwo : public Base {};
class Derived : public DerivedBaseTwo, public DerivedBaseOne 
{};

//somewhere in the code, is Base() called two times here?
Derived * foo = new Derived();
```

Is the `Base()` constructor called twice? And in what order are the constructors called? Base first? Or `DerivedBaseOne()` or `DerivedBaseTwo()` first?

Comment: You may also be thinking of virtual inheritance as this would be slightly different from normal inheritance.

Comment: Inherited constructors is a feature of c++11 and mean completely different thing.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you write it, `Derived` has **two** distinct subobjects of type `Base`, and each gets their own constructor called from the respective `DerivedBaseXXX` constructor of which it is the subobject. The order of calls follows the order of declaration.

By contrast, of you declare `DerivedBaseXXX : virtual public Base`, then there is only **one** `Base` subobject, and its constructor is called from the most derived object, i.e. from the `Derived` object.

(To explain in a bit more detail: A (possibly singly-inheriting) class is constructed by first 1) calling the base class's constructor, then 2) calling the constructors of all member objects in their order of declaration, and finally 3) executing the constructor function body. This applies recursively, and for multiple inheritance, you just replace (1) by calling all the base class's constructors in the order in which the inheritance was declared. Only virtual inheritance adds a genuine extra layer of complication here.)

Answer (score 21):

The order of constructor calls for your inheritance hierarchy will be:

```
Base()  
DerivedBaseTwo()  
Base()
DerivedBaseOne()  
Derived()
```

The order is indeed well-defined and depends on the order in which you mention the derivation for base classes and the order in which you declare members in the class for members.  (See the reference from the C++ Standard below.)

**Does the Base() constructor get called twice?**
**YES**

The `Base()` class constructor gets called here twice, because two classes `DerivedBaseTwo()` and `DerivedBaseOne()` derive from it, so the base class constructor gets called once for each of them.  Your `Derived` class has two distinct `Base` subobjects through multiple paths (one through `DerivedBaseOne()` and the other though `DerivedBaseTwo()`).

The hierarchy of classes you have with multiple inheritance is unusual and it leads to a problem called the **[Diamond Shaped Inheritance Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)**.  To avoid this problem C++ introduces the concept of **[Virtual base class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr135.htm)**.

---

Reference:

**C++03 Standard:  12.6.2/5, Initializing bases and members**

> Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class as described below, virtual base classes shall be initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base class names in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes shall be initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the body of the constructor is executed.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I thought it was the order of declaration (including inheritance declaration) that matters.

Comment: Yeah, @Kerrek is right. The initialization list's order has no effect on anything (unfortunately. That would have been more intuitive IMO)

Comment: The order of the members in the initializer list is ignored by the compiler (it is irrelevant). Not sure I agree with jalf that would have been more intuitive, but I do think it should have been an error to have the initializer list in a different order than declaration.

Comment: Luckily, good compilers warn you if the initializer list does not follow the order of declaration.

Comment: @Kerrek: You are correct, order in which inheritance is specified and member declaration for members

Comment: @jalf: it mirrors the destructor. And since there are multiple ctors and only one dtor, the order has to be consistent across ctors and initialization lists. "member order" is trivial, consistent, and not that bad for memory access patterns.

Comment: @MSalters I know, but despite the technical problems, I still think it is intuitive to expect that the order things are specified in the constructor defines the order in which they're actually constructed.

Comment: Constructor of the `Base` class in this case will not be called twice but only once. Virtual inheritance, which is not actually used in the code of the question, ensures this. Nevertheless, code in the question is not compilable as the virtual inheritance is not used which is necessary in a case of diamond class inheritance.

Comment: @jalf The committee must have been prescient: [C++11's default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) would be a mess to introduce were the constructor initialization list's order significant. There'd be no sane way to make them interoperate. If one wants to have a different logical order of members for ease of understanding, one can use a clang rewriter to reorder them according to their dependency graph (i.e. if member `b` uses the value of member `a` in its direct initializer, its declaration must succeed that of `a`, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

This is answered in: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.14

> The very first constructors to be executed are the virtual base classes anywhere in the hierarchy. They are executed in the order they appear in a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the graph of base classes, where left to right refer to the order of appearance of base class names.

Since your multiple inheritance declaration lists `DerivedBaseTwo` first, its construction order will be executed before `DerivedBaseOne`'s.

So in your `Derived` class, `DerivedBaseTwo` and its chain is created first, that is:

1 - `Base` then `DerivedBaseTwo`

And then `DerivedBaseOne` and its chain:

2 - `Base` then `DerivedBaseOne`

And then:

3 - `Derived` is created after everything else.

Also, with multiple inheritance be mindful of the [Diamond Inheritance Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)

Comment: @Tux-D: maybe not in his example code, but he could run into it in the future. Guess my wording stunk~!