# Avoid calling base constructor 2 times

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have several classes that inherit like so.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {std::cout << "a";}
};

struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};

struct D : B, C {};

int main {
    D d;
}
```

On executing the program, as expected, I see two A objects were constructed, one for the B and one for the C object that are constructed when creating a D object. Whoever, how can I not create two A objects? I want the same A object to be used to create B and C objects. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, are multiple-inherited constructors called multiple times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405839/c-are-multiple-inherited-constructors-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `B` and `C` both use [virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class) for `A`, then there will only be a single base class object for each `D` object:

```
struct B : virtual A {};
struct C : virtual A {};

//...
D d; //prints "a" rather than "aa"
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36f7707968d4008b)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a non-polymorphic solution, you're out of luck. Otherwise, change to the following:

```
struct B : virtual A {};
struct C : virtual A {};
```

Answer (score 1):

As written, every `D` object has two sub-objects of type `A`, one inherited from class `B` and one inherited from class `C`. So the constructor of `A` **must** run twice, once for each sub-object.

If the original design is wrong, and there should only be one `A` sub-object, despite the use of two bases `B` and `C`, the change is to make `A` a virtual base of `B` and a virtual base of `C`. That way there will only be one `A` sub-object in a `D` object, and the constructor of `A` will only run once when a `D` object is constructed.